# Why is this POST request through HttpURLConnection throwing a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, upload, httpurlconnection

Update 3: I tried to execute this request against requestb.in insteaad of the Blobstore URL and the same exception occured, so this looks like a problem with my upload method using HttpURLConnection and not a Blobstore specific issue.

Update 2: Added code for creating the upload URL method at the bottom

Update 1: Added code and exact exception below the question. Hope the situation is clearer now.

Files are getting uploaded to the Blobstore using a POST request to the URL provided by the `createUploadURL()` method. However, App Engine still responds with a FileNotFoundException to the upload requests complaining that a file was not found at `https://<app-id>.appspot.com/_ah/upload/<long-random-string>`

What could be going on here?

Upload Code:

```
try {
    MultipartUtility multipartUtility = new MultipartUtility(blobUploadURL, "UTF-8",writeListener);
    multipartUtility.addFormField("key_name", keyName);
    multipartUtility.addFilePart("file", fileName, is);
    multipartUtility.finish();

} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

MultipartUtility Class:

```
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private WriteListener listener;

    public static interface WriteListener{

        void transferred(long num);

    }

    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset,WriteListener listener)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(-1);
        outputStream=httpConn.getOutputStream();
        this.listener=listener;
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }


    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }


    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, String fileName, InputStream is)
            throws IOException {
        //String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpConn.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.add(line);
        }

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }


        reader.close();
        httpConn.disconnect();

        return response;
    }

}
```

IO Exception caught when the upload request is executed:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://<app-id>.appspot.com/_ah/upload/<random-long-string>
```

Code for creating the Blobstore upload URL: (Note that I can see the uploaded files in Blobstore and even confirm that the blob handler servlet is also getting the key of the uploaded blob despite this exception.)

```
BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String blobUploadURL = bs.createUploadUrl("/save/blob");
```

Comment: please show your code and actual exception

Comment: Seems like a problem creating the upload URL please provide the code for that

Comment: @jirungaray, I have added the upload URL creation code in the question. To me, it seems that the HttpURLConnection is probably trying to access the file after it has been uploaded to the Blobstore URL. However, I don't see what could be triggering perhaps a GET request to this URL.

Comment: Just checked this request against requestb.in and the same error appeared. So it looks like this has to do with HttpURLConnection object and not Blobstore.